# How to open OpenX ads in new window / tabs

Tags: javascript, overlay, openx

I created an overlay ad server within OpenX. When I create the invocation code to give to publishers, I would like the campaigns, once clicked, to open in a new tab or window. What code can I use? Right now I am using `a target="_blank`.

Comment: This question requires some more information like... Have you tried anything yet? Where's the actual code? What IS happening?

Answer (score 0):

The target settings are configured per ad within OpenX. It's not part of the invocation code as it would be overwritten when the OpenX JS is executed.